# Given a smooth norm, does there exist a nice function of that norm which is smooth in the whole space?

Tags: banach-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $(X,\|\cdot\|)$ be a Banach space such that the norm $\|\cdot\|$ is Fréchet smooth in $X\backslash\{0\}$. In a Hilbert $H$ space the square of the norm is a function which is Fréchet smooth in all af $H$.

The question is thus the following: does there exist $f:\mathbb{R}_+\to\mathbb{R}_+$ strictly increasing with $f(0)=0$, such that the composition $f(\|\cdot\|)$ is smooth everywhere?

In the Hilbert case, one of these functions would be $f(x)=x^2$.

Comment: By smooth do you mean infinitely differentiable?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. By smooth I mean continuously differentiable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $x \mapsto x^2$ works in general.

Let $n(x) = \|x\|$, then $\|Dn(x)\| \le 1$ since the norm is Lipchitz.

If we let $s(x) = n(x)^2$, then we see that $\|s(x)-0\| \le \|x\|^2$ hence $s$ is Frechet differentiable at $x=0$ with derivative $Ds(0) = 0$.

All that remains is to show that $Ds$ is continuous at $x=0$.

Note that for $x \neq 0$ we have $Ds(x) = x Dn(x)$, hence 
$\|Ds(x)\| \le \|x\|$, from which the desired result follows.

Comment: You're right! Thank you for the answer.